# Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard way Tutorial

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and currently going through the exercises in Zed Shaw's Python book.
In Zed's Ex41, there is this function:

```
def runner(map, start):
     next = start

     while True:
         room = map[next]
         print "\n-------"
         next = room()
```

My question is, why did he have to assign 'start' to the variable 'next' when he could have used 'start' straight away? Why didn't he just do this?

```
def runner(map, start):


     while True:
         room = map[start]
         print "\n-------"
         start = room()
```

Because this function also seem to work. Thanks

Comment: Although this book is far from the most used and recommended Python tutorial, it is with a large margin the one we get the most "Huh?" questions about here on SO.

Try http://diveintopython.org/ instead.

Comment: Just helped a colleague out with that same function. Some other things in that exercise I thought could be improved: - use of "map" as a variable name - the "ROOMS" dictionary keys being strings exactly matching the functions which were their values

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second example works, yes, but he's trying to write a Python tutorial style book, and I think the first one is much more clear about exactly what's going on. `start` as a variable name loses meaning when it's no longer the actual `start`, but instead the `next` room that we're going into.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Good to know. I really thought I was missing something. Stackoverflow rocks! I will be back ;)

Answer (score 10):

I think it was done for readability. In the programmer's mind, `start` is supposed to represent the start of something. `next` was presumably supposed to represent the next item.

You are correct that the code could be shortened, but it mangles the meaning of `start`.

Note that in current versions of Python (2.6 or later), `next` is a built-in function, so it's no longer a good idea to name a variable `next`.

Comment: Thank you. Am using python 2.6. Zed actually talked about not using built-in function as variable eg. map. I will take note.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's just for readability. When writing code, you should always keep in mind that variables (and also functions, classes etc) should always have meaningful names, otherwise reading your code will be a nightmare. The meaning of the variable in the loop is to hold the **next** item, not the **start** item.

Answer (score 0):

He didn't *have* to, but did for naming-style considerations.